# Determine if Rails Resource Controller has an Action Enabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

I have a Rails 3 app and am writing an "administrative" partial I'd like to include in views across many different models. The partial will include resourceful links (e.g. new, index, show), but my design fails if the resource has a route (e.g. index) disabled in routes.rb.

A sample view (views/my_resources/show.html.erb):

```
<% provide(:title, 'My Resource') %>

<div style="float:right;">
  <%= render '/shared/resource_menu' %>
</div>

<h1>My Resource</h1>
<%= @my_resource.name %>
```

Excerpt from /shared/_resource_menu.html.erb:

```
<div class="submenu">
 <b><%= File.basename(params[:controller]).pluralize.titleize %></b><br />
 <% if params[:action] != 'index' %>
  <%= link_to 'Index', url_for(:controller => params[:controller], :action => 'index', :only_path => true) %><br />
 <% end %>
 <% if params[:action] != 'new' %>
  <%= link_to 'New', url_for(:controller => params[:controller], :action => 'new', :only_path => true) %><br />
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Currently, I've hacked it so that each conditional looks like:

```
<% if params[:action] != 'index' && !@omit_index_in_resource_menu %>
```

and I set the `@omit_index_in_resource_menu` by hand in the relevant controllers, but that's clunkier than I would prefer.

Can I instead do something more elegant like:

```
<% if params[:action] != 'index' && controller.actions.include?('index') %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would help you:

`UsersController.action_methods` (it's a class method)

or

`UsersController.new.available_action? :index` (it's an instance method)

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Base.html#method-i-action_methods

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. I need to get better at searching the API apparently...

Comment: You can also use autocompletion in the console to find your API sometimes, or call `methods` on an object. It's a good starting point when you are looking for something. Cheers :)